# My Python script is adding extra unwanted characters to my string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to format a file path inside of a string but it keeps adding extra '\'.

```
template = "{%% extends 'base.html' %%}"\
"{%% block content %%}"\
"                   "\
"<h1>%s</h2>"\
"                    "\
"<p>%s</p>           "\
"<p><img src= '%s'></p>"\
"{%% endblock %%}" %(title, text, img_path)
```

it returns this.

```
 <p><img src= \'myDirectory/scarlett Johanson/1448556501.89.jpg\'></p>{% endblock %}'}
```

I don't want the \ before the string and after jpg inside the string. I have tried to slice the last character out of the string but it just removes g and leaves \ at the end. what is confusing me though is that it places \ before 'myDirectory.

I am creating the files with

```
title = time.time()
file_path = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, '%s.jpg') % title
```

Comment: you can create multiline string with triple quote ... `""" hello """`

Comment: Sounds like your templating system escapes the string, which is unrelated to this code.

Comment: Doesn't it only **display** escaped quote when you print the string representation ? I think you just got fooled by what you see

Comment: @Cyrbil Thankyou, I wasn't aware of that. I was copying my code from the terminal in to a file I'll just try writing it to a file. Is that a python thing or a jinga2 thing?

Comment: If you are trying on the terminal, instead of typing just `template` try with `print(template)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks, I put 'print template' in the for loop which the template is created in and it removes the \ but I still get the \ when I print the the function.

Comment: @EricMacLeod: what do you mean with "print the function"? Please include the full code in your question, otherwise it's impossible to figure out what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you can close the question.

When you print a string representation to the console, it is return quoted.

so `print(repr('hello'))` will output `'hello'`

If the string contain quotes, it will be escaped, even if not escaped before:

`print(repr("'hello'"))` gives `'\'hello\''`
`print(repr('\'hello\''))` gives `'\'hello\''`
`print(repr("""'hello'"""))` gives `'\'hello\''`

Since your are printing a dict that contain a string, the string will get outputted quoted. `print({'a', 'hello'})` gives `{'a': 'hello'}`

Comment: That's not really accurate. `print "'hello'"` prints `'hello'`. You're possibly confusing `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. Even when `__repr__` is called, it won't automatically escape characters if it's not needed (e.g. `print "\"hello\"".__repr__()` prints `'"hello"'`).

Comment: I wrote it in a rush, thx for the remainder. Answer edited. Also that I was talking in the context or a repl (which quote the string). It wasn't clear in my post

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using tripple quotes with a string formatter?

```
template = """
    {%% extends 'base.html' %%}
    {%% block content %%}

    <h1>{title}</h2>

    <p>{text}</p>
    <p><img src={img_path}></p>
    {%% endblock %%}
""".format(title=title, text=text, img_path=img_path)
```

single quotes shouldn't be used for html attributes

try printing your template to see what you get

```
print(template)
```

Comment: @EricMacLeod did you change your quotes to be double quotes? also try removing the quotes completely and see what it does

Comment: yeah it was double quotes, I think it might be a jinga 2 thing, like Cyrbil said it might be just the what's displayed in the terminal. I'm going to try writing it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but maybe you could use this after you create the template variable:

```
template=template.replace("\\'","'")
```

I believe that something goes on with quote escaping though, at some other part of your code....

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry I’m not sure what’s causing the error. However, one way to deal with it is to just use `replace`. I’m not familiar with your template renderer (I’ve only used jinja2) but it needs to be something like this:

```
s = s.replace("/","")
```